# Does this Question make sense, 'the background of which they come'?

Tags: sentence-construction

One of my friends is writing a paper and asked me to edit it for her, and for some reason, 'the background of which they come' doesn't make any sense. If it helps, the beginning of the sentence is 'all the players state there name and 'the background of which they come''.

Thanks! The insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "...all the players state **their** name and background."

Comment: "... and the background **from** which they come."  You come **from** somewhere, you go **to** somewhere.  "Of" would be for more intricate things: "... and the thing **of** which they are most proud."

Comment: Seriously? You seem to be a native speaker. What background do you come **from**? :)

Answer (score 0):

The preposition used should be *from*, not *of*.

To make this clearer, compare the following sentences with the preposition moved to the end:

> ✘ The background they come **of**.
>   ✔ The background they come **from**.

Alternatively, you can use different wording:

> ✘ They come **of** a certain background.
>   ✔ They come **from** a certain background.

---

Once the correct preposition is identified, you can refer back to the original wording:

> ✘ The background **of** which they come.
>   ✔ The background **from** which they come.

---

Note that I don't think *of* is strictly ungrammatical in every case. It's a preposition I've seen used in this way in some rare pieces of writing—and in a specifically different construction than I used here. However, it's very uncommon and wouldn't normally be considered idiomatic. (And at a certain point, something becomes effectively ungrammatical simply because it's so unidiomatic.) Unless you are certain of its use in the right context, it's best to stick to the far more common *from*.